# Android: How can I use quadTo in Path class correctly?

Tags: android

I was trying to start a quadratic curve from (0, 0) to the bottom right of my device screen. I did some research and looks like I can use quadTo method in the Path class to achieve that. I wrote the following code but I don't see the curve is drawn:

```
int w = getDisplayWidth();
int h = getDisplayHeight();

Paint paint  = new Paint();
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

PointF pt1 = new PointF(0, 0);
PointF pt2 = new PointF(w, h);

Path path = new Path();
// Find the mid point
float x2 = (pt2.x + pt1.x)/2;
float y2 = (pt2.y + pt1.y)/2;
// Move the path to the mid point
path.moveTo(x2, y2);

// Draw a cruve from 0,0 to w, h
path.quadTo(pt1.x, pt1.y, pt2.x, pt2.y);
m_canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

The output is the image below:

[image]

Did I miss something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation:

> void quadTo(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2)
>
> Add a quadratic bezier from the last point, approaching control point
>   (x1,y1), and ending at (x2,y2).

Currently you are drawing a curve starting in the middle of the screen (x2,y2), through the (0,0) point and ending in (width, height).

Try something like this:

```
PointF pt1 = new PointF(0, 0);
PointF pt2 = new PointF(w, h);

PointF mid = new PointF(w, h/2);

Path path = new Path();
path.moveTo(0, 0);
path.quadTo(mid.x, mid.y, pt2.x, pt2.y);
```